# Is the usage of ON DELETE CASCADE wrong or not allowed on wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, database, mysql

I have table with foreign key reference and i recently changed the create table query with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

```
$wpdb->query("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS $table_name2");  
    //CREATE TABLE bmg_CompanyCategoryCross
        $sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS $table_name2 (
        id mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
        companyid mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
        categoryid mediumint(9) NOT NULL,       
        PRIMARY KEY  (id),
        FOREIGN KEY  (companyid) REFERENCES $table_name(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY  (categoryid) REFERENCES $table_name3(id)
    ) $charset_collate;";
         $wpdb->query($sql);
```

This table is creating on my local machine but not on live server. Is the usage of `ON DELETE CASCADE` wrong or not allowed on wordpress?